# Add more events to an existing fullcalendar with EventSources

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm working with Fullcalendar and I have an existing calendar, I want to add more events to it using the eventSources array.

```
calendarDiv.fullCalendar({eventSources: [ { url:url ,className: "class"}] })
```

But this creates a new calendar instead of putting all the events on the calendar that I already have. Can someone tell me how to add more events to the calendar using this? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `eventSources` to add *additional* sources is not the proper way. The proper way, like Will said, is to use [`addEventSource`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/), you're just not using it correctly. Since you have a URL you just need to pass the URL:

```
calendarDiv.fullCalendar('addEventSource', url);
```

Aditionally, if you want a specific [`className`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) you should add that to the source (back-end).

Comment: This worked! i have to see how i add the classname, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overwriting all of the calendar events.

I believe you want addEventSource. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/

```
calendarDiv.fullCalendar('addEventSource', [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2010-01-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2010-01-05',
            end    : '2010-01-07'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
            allDay : false // will make the time show
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't worked. i've tried that like this 

calendarDiv.fullCalendar('addEventSource',[url:'/calendar/evaluations/' + selected_course,className: "evaluation"])

Like this

calendarDiv.fullCalendar('addEventSource',{eventSources: [ { url:'/calendar/evaluations/' + selected_course,className: "evaluation"}] })

And nothing works... any ideas?

Comment: I've never used Fullcalendar, I'm just going by the documentation. It seems a little misleading. The `addEventSource` docs say, "source may be an Array/URL/Function just as in the events option" but looking that the events options, it appears that it takes an object with one property called `events` and THAT takes an array.